# npm WARN deprecated minimatch

Tags: node.js, npm

How ii'm trying to execute npm install butit gives me this error:

> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

I'm using node v4.1.1

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: It seems like `minimatch` package needs an update. Have you tried `npm update -g  minimatch` ?

Comment: you mean npm update  -g minimatch

Comment: i tried that but the same problem

Answer (score 2):

If you did not install minimatch yourself, it is likely a dependency of a package you installed.

In your project dir, type `npm ls` and search for the package using minimatch. If you want the warning removed, you can stop using that package or kindly ask the maintainer to update his dependencies on Github.

Comment: so what should i do to fix this prob??

Comment: As I said, stop using the package that has a dependency on a deprecated library or contact the maintainer. There is no other way.

Comment: can you provide your package.json?

Comment: are u still here??

Comment: yeah please post your package.json